# Проблема url запрет ввода ссылки после расширения

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, site

Как запретить ввод текста после `.php`?

**Пример**

```
site.ru/index.php/bla/
```

При таком запросе отображается *index.php*, но без подключения *css* и др. библиотек.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, при таких станицах должно выдавать 404, а выдаёт 200 ОК

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `RewriteBase /` в .htaccess

Если не поможет, следует стили и прочее подключать вот так

```
rel="/css/style.css"
```

а не вот так

```
rel="css/style.css"
```

Comment: Попробовал 1 не помогло

Comment: Спасибо, помогло 2 вариант)